# tycho compiler-plugin cannot compile

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, tycho

When building an OSGI bundle with tycho, the compiler-plugin throws the following error:

```
   ...AnswerServlet.java:[307]
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The method setCharacterEncoding(String) is undefined for the type HTTPServletResponse
```

As you can see, the Class `HTTPServletResponse` can be resolved from the build path (the package `javax.servlet`) successfully, but the Class seems not to have the function `setCharacterEncoding(...)`.

Invesitgations showed, that this method is only included of `javax.servlet` 2.4+.

However, i am using version 3. There is no other version of this library on my entire file system...so how is that possible?

Building in a standalone java file against this lib/Class/function also works well. Only the tycho compiler plugins fails.

Moreover, i activated the debug-log where the compiler-plugin lists all the build-path. The only entry about `javax.servlet` was corret.

```
~\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar[+javax/servlet/*;+javax/servlet/http/*;+javax/servlet/annotation/*;+javax/servlet/descriptor/*;+javax/servlet/resources/*;?**/*]
```

Moreover, there were no other relations to any other `javax.servlet`things.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The bundle requiring javax.servlet had itself a crappy javax.servlet-jar in it. Seems like maven/tycho priorized this one for the build. Now, I removed it and tycho uses the javax.servlet library from the target platform